# Vue.js2 v-for separate protperties

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

With the code below, if I press the "Edit" button, I change the disabled state all the rows, how can I separate this? I mean, once i just want to edit one row.

```
        cols="12"
        class="contact-container"
        v-for="contact in contacts"
        :key="contact.id"
      >
        <b-form inline>
          <b-input
            type="text"
            :value="contact.name"
            :disabled="editMode ? disabled : ''"
          />
          <b-input
            type="tel"
            :value="contact.phoneNumber"
            :disabled="editMode ? disabled : ''"
          />
          <b-input
            type="email"
            :value="contact.email"
            :disabled="editMode ? disabled : ''"
          />
          <b-input
            type="text"
            :value="contact.title"
            :disabled="editMode ? disabled : ''"
          />
          <b-button-group>
            <button type="button" size="lg" class="btn">
              <b-icon-x-circle-fill variant="danger"></b-icon-x-circle-fill>
            </button>
            <button type="button" size="lg" class="btn" @click="startEdit">
              <b-icon-pencil-fill variant="primary"></b-icon-pencil-fill>
            </button>
          </b-button-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `editMode` is part of the components' `data`. If it's a `prop` this solution might be a bit tricky to implement.

Set up `editMode` as an empty object in your component's data. And for the method `startEdit` it should take, as a parameter, the id of the contact being edited.

So something like this: `@click="startEdit(contact.id)"`. and in the method body, `this.$set(this.editMode, contact.id, true)`. See [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in Vue docs for information on `this.$set`.

To check if a row is disabled use `:disabled="editMode[contact.id]"` (no need for ternary operator checking as it's a boolean)

This approach will make it possible to edit multiple rows at the same time. Though a name such as `editedContacts` might be better in this case.

Comment: It's working now, I'll check your solution too. ( I'm a newbie, and stackoverflow says avoid "thanks" :D) I solved in the following way: 
`async getContacts() {
      const request = await fetch("https://localhost:6001/contact");
      var data = await request.json();
      data.forEach((element) => {
        element.disabled = true;
      });
      this.contacts = data;
      console.log(this.contacts);
    },`
In the fetch method, added a property, and then i can bind the input:
 `:disabled="contact.disabled" `

Update: uhh, i cant format the code in my comment? :)